# Flex - mxml- change visibility of identfied obiects

Tags: flex4, mxml

Let's consider an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:local="*">

<s:Button id="button""/>    
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

By detault mxml compiler makes "button" a public field of the generated class.
Is it porribie to force it to make it a private field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't make it private using plain MXML.**

Nevertheless, there is a hacky way - removing the "id" property will effectively make it private. If you still need reference to the object, you should add a "creationComplete" handler and keep the reference from the event target.

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    [Bindable] private var button:Button;

    private function onMyButtonCreationComplete(event:Event):void {
        button = Button(event.target);
    }
]]> 
</fx:Script>

...

<s:Button creationComplete="onMyButtonCreationComplete(event)"/>
```

This effectively the same as a private "button" in your example.